# Предложение открыть ссылку в мобильном приложении

Tags: angular, мобильные-приложения, angular-routing

Проект написан на Ангуляр, есть мобильное приложение для ios/android.

Сейчас стоит задача, чтобы при открытии любой ссылки веб-версии с мобильного устройства предлагалось открыть ее в мобильном приложении или, если нет приложения, то ссылка на маркет.

Может кто-то подсказать, что потребуется, чтобы реализовать это и в каком направлении вообще двигаться?

По такой аналогии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вообще для такого обычно добавляют **intent-filter** внутри манифеста самого мобильного приложения,

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="my_scheme" android:host="my_host" />
        </intent-filter>
```

А вот пример ссылки для открытия **HTML**

```
<a href="intent://my_host#Intent;scheme=my_scheme;action=my_action;end">Открыть приложение</a>
```

**Рекомендую прочитать**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser